# Python 3.6 : TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to run this module but it gives me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python36/django file/mysite/personal\crawler.py", line 105, in crawl
        self._crawl([u_parse.path], self.depth)
      File "C:/Python36/django file/mysite/personal\crawler.py", line 132, in _crawl
        html = self.get(url)
      File "C:/Python36/django file/mysite/personal\crawler.py", line 117, in get
        page = self.curl(url)
      File "C:/Python36/django file/mysite/personal\crawler.py", line 144, in curl
        req = urllib.request('%s://%s%s' % (self.scheme, self.domain, url))
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm trying to run a search engine for my web project, and it appears I have done something wrong at the code.

here's the code for crawler.py

```
import sqlite3  
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from html.parser import HTMLParser  
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class HREFParser(HTMLParser):  
    """
    Parser that extracts hrefs
    """
    hrefs = set()
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            dict_attrs = dict(attrs)
            if dict_attrs.get('href'):
                self.hrefs.add(dict_attrs['href'])


def get_local_links(html, domain):  
    """
    Read through HTML content and returns a tuple of links
    internal to the given domain
    """
    hrefs = set()
    parser = HREFParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    for href in parser.hrefs:
        u_parse = urlparse(href)
        if href.startswith('/'):
            # purposefully using path, no query, no hash
            hrefs.add(u_parse.path)
        else:
          # only keep the local urls
          if u_parse.netloc == domain:
            hrefs.add(u_parse.path)
    return hrefs


class CrawlerCache(object):  
    """
    Crawler data caching per relative URL and domain.
    """
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sites
            (domain text, url text, content text)''')
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def set(self, domain, url, data):
        """
        store the content for a given domain and relative url
        """
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO sites VALUES (?,?,?)",
            (domain, url, data))
        self.conn.commit()

    def get(self, domain, url):
        """
        return the content for a given domain and relative url
        """
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT content FROM sites WHERE domain=? and url=?",
            (domain, url))
        row = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if row:
            return row[0]

    def get_urls(self, domain):
        """
        return all the URLS within a domain
        """
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM sites WHERE domain=?", (domain,))
        # could use fetchone and yield but I want to release
        # my cursor after the call. I could have create a new cursor tho.
        # ...Oh well
        return [row[0] for row in self.cursor.fetchall()]


class Crawler(object):  
    def __init__(self, cache=None, depth=2):
        """
        depth: how many time it will bounce from page one (optional)
        cache: a basic cache controller (optional)
        """
        self.depth = depth
        self.content = {}
        self.cache = cache

    def crawl(self, url, no_cache=None):
        """
        url: where we start crawling, should be a complete URL like
        'http://www.intel.com/news/'
        no_cache: function returning True if the url should be refreshed
        """
        u_parse = urlparse(url)
        self.domain = u_parse.netloc
        self.content[self.domain] = {}
        self.scheme = u_parse.scheme
        self.no_cache = no_cache
        self._crawl([u_parse.path], self.depth)

    def set(self, url, html):
        self.content[self.domain][url] = html
        if self.is_cacheable(url):
            self.cache.set(self.domain, url, html)

    def get(self, url):
        page = None
        if self.is_cacheable(url):
          page = self.cache.get(self.domain, url)
        if page is None:
          page = self.curl(url)
        else:
          print ("cached url... [%s] %s" % (self.domain, url))
        return page

    def is_cacheable(self, url):
        return self.cache and self.no_cache \
            and not self.no_cache(url)

    def _crawl(self, urls, max_depth):
        n_urls = set()
        if max_depth:
            for url in urls:
                # do not crawl twice the same page
                if url not in self.content:
                    html = self.get(url)
                    self.set(url, html)
                    n_urls = n_urls.union(get_local_links(html, self.domain))
            self._crawl(n_urls, max_depth-1)

    def curl(self, url):
        """
        return content at url.
        return empty string if response raise an HTTPError (not found, 500...)
        """
        try:
            print ("retrieving url... [%s] %s" % (self.domain, url))
            req = urllib.request('%s://%s%s' % (self.scheme, self.domain, url))
            response = urllib.urlopen(req)
            return response.read().decode('ascii', 'ignore')
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            print ("error [%s] %s: %s" % (self.domain, url, e))
            return ''
```

and for the test run file "run.py"

```
import re
from crawler import Crawler, CrawlerCache

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # Using SQLite as a cache to avoid pulling twice
    crawler = Crawler(CrawlerCache('crawler.db'))
    root_re = re.compile('^/$').match
    crawler.crawl('http://techcrunch.com/', no_cache=root_re)
    crawler.crawl('http://www.engadget.com/', no_cache=root_re)
    crawler.crawl('http://gizmodo.com/', no_cache=root_re)
    crawler.crawl('http://www.zdnet.com/', no_cache=root_re)
    crawler.crawl('http://www.wired.com/', no_cache=root_re)
```

I tried to fix it but still, It gives me the same error.

Anyone, please help me out.

Comment: `urllib.request` is a module, not a function. You cannot call it like you do here: `req = urllib.request('%s://%s%s' % (self.scheme, self.domain, url))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `curl` method:

```
def curl(self, url):
    """
    return content at url.
    return empty string if response raise an HTTPError (not found, 500...)
    """
    try:
        print ("retrieving url... [%s] %s" % (self.domain, url))
        # You're calling a module here. urllib.request is not a function
        req = urllib.request('%s://%s%s' % (self.scheme, self.domain, url))
        response = urllib.urlopen(req)
        return response.read().decode('ascii', 'ignore')
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print ("error [%s] %s: %s" % (self.domain, url, e))
        return ''
```

Replace the `urllib.request` line by as `urllib.request.urlopen` call:

```
def curl(self, url):
    """
    return content at url.
    return empty string if response raise an HTTPError (not found, 500...)
    """
    try:
        print ("retrieving url... [%s] %s" % (self.domain, url))
        # You're calling a module here. urllib.request is not a function
        req = urllib.request.urlopen('%s://%s%s' % (self.scheme, self.domain, url))
        response = urllib.urlopen(req)
        return response.read().decode('ascii', 'ignore')
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print ("error [%s] %s: %s" % (self.domain, url, e))
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to call a module:

```
req = urllib.request('%s://%s%s' % (self.scheme, self.domain, url))
```

You are looking for the class `Request`:

```
req = urllib.request.Request('%s://%s%s' % (self.scheme, self.domain, url))
```

All in `crawler.py` in line 144.